# Filling redux state with key objects from API endpoint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

If I dispatch `dispatch(fetchResources());` this in a component I add these two objects to the Redux state. When I call the function again i expect that the two new object from the response are being added to the list. Instead it created a new array for the response. How can i make sure it gets added to the array instead of getting a new array every time. (see image)

[image]

**Interface:**

```
export interface Resource {
    [key: string]: Object[]
}

export interface AddResourceInterface {
    type: typeof ADD_RESOURCE;
    payload: Resource;
}

export type ResourceTypes =
    AddResourceInterface |
    RemoveResourceInterface;

export type AppActions = ResourceTypes;
```

**Action:**

```
export const addResource = (resource: Resource): AppActions  => ({
    type: ADD_RESOURCE,
    payload: resource
});

export const fetchResources: ActionCreator<ThunkAction<any, any, any, any>> = () => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {

        await fetch('http://localhost:3000/authorization')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                dispatch(addResource(data))
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }
};
```

**Reducer:**

```
const initialState: Resource[] = [];

const resourceReducer = (
    state = initialState,
    action: ResourceTypes
): Resource[] => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_RESOURCE":
            return [...state, action.payload];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**Endpoint returns:**

```
{
  "https://google.com": {
    "enters": "today",
    "scopes": [
      "cloud:user"
    ]
  },
  "https://youtube.com": {
    "enters": "today",
    "scopes": [
      "cloud:user"
    ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the previous values in your state and if you absolutely want them to override every time you dispatch the action then you can just change the reducer to this:

```
const resourceReducer = (
    state = initialState,
    action: ResourceTypes
): Resource[] => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_RESOURCE":
            return [action.payload];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

So `return action.payload` will assign the array to the state now. Previously you used spread operator like `[...state, action.payload]` so it will create a new array with the previous values and the new values.

Comment: Yes i want to override the previous state, this is an exception case. But when i try your answer typescript starts complaining about the type of the payload. 
Type 'Resource' is missing the following properties from type 'Resource[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
I guess you put an ignore on it?

Comment: @Marc Hmm, your response is an object and your initialState is an array. You can either change the types or you can simply change `return action.payload;` to `return [action.payload];`.